# How do I say "this argument needs to allow arbitrary attribute assignment" in Python type hinting?

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

I have a function whose job is to assign an arbitrary object to an arbitrary attribute name to a target object.  If `tgt` quacks like a `dict` (sorry for the pun, if it is a mutable hashmap-type object), it should use `tgt[attrname] = obj`, else it will call `setattr(tgt, attrname, obj)`.  How do I tell mypy and the type system that I really need a `tgt` that allows assignments to arbitrary names?

```
from typing import MutableMapping, Any, Union

def assignment_func(tgt : Union[MutableMapping, Any], attrname: str, obj: object):
    """
    assign `obj` to `tgt` using the attrname. 
    setitem dict-type behavior takes precedence
    """

    try:
        if callable(getattr(tgt, "__getitem__", None)):
            tgt[attrname] = obj
        else:
            setattr(tgt, attrname, obj)
        print("yeehaa!     worked with a %s" % (tgt.__class__.__name__))

    except (Exception,) as e:
        print("bummer, dinna work with a %s.  got a %s" % (tgt.__class__.__name__, e.__class__.__name__))

class Foo:
    pass

class BadSlot:
    """unknown `bar` will blow this up"""
    __slots__ = "zoom"

class GoodSlot:
    """
    works.  but the attribute name can be anything 
    so, this, and anything with __slots___ should really be 
    flagged as a problem by mypy
    """
    __slots__ = "bar"

#mypy should complain about list, object, GoodSlot and BadSlot
#Foo and a dict both support arbitrary assignments.
for tgt in [list(), dict(), object(), Foo(), GoodSlot(), BadSlot()]:
    assignment_func(tgt, "bar", "coucou")
```

#### output:

```
bummer, dinna work with a list.  got a TypeError
yeehaa!     worked with a dict
bummer, dinna work with a object.  got a AttributeError
yeehaa!     worked with a Foo
yeehaa!     worked with a GoodSlot
bummer, dinna work with a BadSlot.  got a AttributeError
```

#### what does mypy have to say?

nothing.

But if change the hinting to

```
def assignment_func(tgt : Union[MutableMapping, object], attrname: str, obj: object):
```

then it (correctly) reminds me that `object` doesnt support assignments).

`error: Unsupported target for indexed assignment`, with the offending line being `tgt[attrname] = obj` under the MutableMapping condition.

#### Python versions:

the code in question is 2.7/3.6+ code, but let's simplify this to be only applicable to 3.6+.

`tgt` is the only argument I am interested in right here.  Let's assume `attrname` is known to be a correct attribute name (i.e. `attrname` isn't something like `2badcantstartwithnumber`, but could be `toobadcantstartwithnumber` and `obj` doesn't matter (I might want to use `Any` for it, actually).

One recurring source of error in my code is using SQLAlchemy to fetch read-only data.  The result is an iterable ResultProxy, which to minimize RAM use, does not have a `__dict__`.  If I am going to use pass that fetch's rows to **assignment_func** as a tgt, then I need to remember to wrap/process each row, otherwise I get `BadSlot` out of it.  `dict(row)` does fine, but I want to be reminded by `mypy` if at all possible.  Django ORM fetches have the same issue as well.